# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError Firebase and Unity

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine, crash, android-4.4-kitkat

I tried integrating Firebase in my Unity 5.6.2 but the problem is on Android 4 the app is crashing with the following stack trace

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.<clinit>(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.1.0:150)
at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.1.0:53)
  at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo (ContentProvider.java:1598)
  at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo (ContentProvider.java:1569)
  at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo
  at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider (ActivityThread.java:5050)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders (ActivityThread.java:4630)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication (ActivityThread.java:4570)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500 (ActivityThread.java:151)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1285)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:136)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5281)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative (Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:515)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:932)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:748)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main (Native Method)
```

I am not sure how to fix this crash, Please help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup):

> Ensure that your Unity project targets the appropriate OS level:
>
> For iOS — target iOS 8 or later
>
> For Android — target API level 16 (Jelly Bean) or later

It seems that it supports Android 4.1 and above

Answer (score 0):

MIN SDK 16
Target SDK 28

I think I missed to add

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

in custom gradle template and I also added `android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"` 
in application tag in manifest. I updated the game with above yesterday and till now I haven't seen the above error again, seems like it has fixed the issue.